# linking my java web application to the web?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am beginner java web developer, now my question is after i developed my application, how to make users see it on the web?

I used JSF,MySQL and GlassFish server in my development stage and now i want to publish it.

I got a domain name and an a web hosting account on goDaddy.com

In other words what to do after i develope my web application?
what steps should i take in server creation and other stuff?

I have searched alot but there is no specific way for it. I am trying to make this dynamic website based on jsf development--and it is already done--become alive and out their like any other web site?

any guide lines and steps should i take in making this steps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you will need a "Production" server to host the application yourself or use a hosting service of some kind that provides a Java EE container.  If you're tied to Glassfish, you can Google for those providers like http://glassfishhosting.com/.

Other options that might be good fits for you are cloud services.  Something like either [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/) or [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).  Each has their own pricing tiers that scale based on usage.  Good luck to you going Live!

Comment: I have the server(running on windows server) localy at the Ferm for which i've developed my webapp(dynamic website to be exact).
whats the next step for now ? and should i switch to JBoss or glassfish 3 is fine ?

Comment: If you want to host off your own box, you will need to look into something like dyndns (assuming your on cable or dsl) and do a redirect to dyndns url you are provided through godaddy.

Comment: JEE Container is your preference.  Personally, I use JBoss over Glassfish but either can be used.  Since you will be hosting yourself, dardo is correct.  You will need to set up your DNS on that box and set that information with your domain registrar.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814591

Comment: ThanQ you both guys alooot this was so much helpfull :)

Answer (score 2):

Can host the code on Github and push it to Heroku.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the provider you chose but you need a java application server for your live environment. And optimally this should be the same server as your development server.

For our projects we buy a virtual server and install Glassfish on it. This costs around 15 € per month and we have the same environment for development and production.